# Not sure why I'm getting this TypeError

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm using classes and objects to create a list of stuff in javascript (I'm pretty new to programming). Now, I thought I had this right but for some reason it's throwing a

> "Uncaught TypeError: courseList.calculateValue is not a function
> at assignment.js:27"

Can't figure out why this isn't working. Please help!
Here's my code:

[image: my code]

Comment: Please share your code so we can understand the error better

Comment: Brand new to this site. Sorry I tried to add a screenshot of my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Click on the "edit" link and put in the code, not just a screenshot of the code.

Comment: @jellybeanocd, you should copy and paste the code itself not a screen shot of the code.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I'm new to programming and this site so still trying to work everything out. I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You have an object courseList with nested array courses, that actually contains objects of class Course.

courseList doesnt have this methods, because they were defined inside Course class.
To execute this methods you need to do courseList.courses[0].calculateValue() and courseList.courses[1].calculateValue()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling `calculateValue()` on an object that is not a `Course` object.

In your case you need to do `courseList.courses[0].calculateValue()` to calculate the value of the first course. And likewise you can do it for other courses by changing the index.

**Longer explanation**

`courseList` (badly named) is an object with just one property called `courses`.

This property has a value which is a list of `Course` objects. So in order to call methods from the `Course` class on these objects you need to access them by first accessing the value of the `course` property in `courseList` and then choosing one of the courses from the list using an index like `courseList.courses[1]`

`courseList.courses[1]` is now a `Course` object so you can call `calculateValue()` and `printSummary()` on it

**Side Note**

Your `console.log()` statement on line 28 won't print your results (even when you make the fix above) since `printSummary` doesn't return anything. You don't need to call `console.log()` on it at all, since `printSummary` handles the printing within it

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now. I really appreciate it

Comment: glad to hear it! please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work